# Update a resource file dynamically

Tags: c#

We have a Res1.resx and it has a file1.doc.
Later we would like to replace file1.doc with file2.doc in the resx file based on business rule. How to achieve this.
Thanks
N

Comment: Programmatically replace the contents of a resource file after the project is compiled? Is that what you need?

Comment: Wait a sec! A business rule affecting a Resource File?! What do you mean?

Comment: ::Programmatically replace the contents of a resource file after the ::project is compiled?

Yes.

Answer (score 5):

you should have a look at [ResXResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter.aspx) and [ResXResourceReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx)

Comment: Let's hope the question wasn't about changing a compiled resource, instead of a .resx

Answer (score 2):

Sorry,i don't think that this could be possible

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do that. Here's a bit of code we use. Please let me know if you need more details.

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets or replaces the ResourceDictionary by dynamically loading
/// a Localization ResourceDictionary from the file path passed in.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="resourceDictionaryFile">The resource dictionary to use to set/replace
/// the ResourceDictionary.</param>
private void SetCultureResourceDictionary(String resourceDictionaryFile)
{
    // Scan all resource dictionaries and remove, if it is string resource distionary
    for ( int index= 0; index < Resources.MergedDictionaries.Count; ++index)
    {
        // Look for an indicator in the resource file that indicates that this
        // is a dynamic file that should be removed before loading its replacement.
        if (Resources.MergedDictionaries[index].Contains("ResourceDictionaryName"))
        {
            if ( File.Exists(resourceDictionaryFile) )
            {
                Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(Resources.MergedDictionaries[index]);
            }
        }
    }

    // read required resource file to resource dictionary and add to MergedDictionaries collection
    ResourceDictionary newResourceDictionary =  new ResourceDictionary();
    newResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri(resourceDictionaryFile);
    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newResourceDictionary);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to modify the compiled resource at runtime, I don't think it's possible, at least not without ugly hacks. Anyway, it doesn't make sense: if it's a resource, it's not meant to be modified; and if it needs to be modified, it shouldn't be a resource.